# Equivalence of categroies between representations of $\operatorname{Sp}(2g;\mathbb{Q})$ and $\mathfrak{sp}(2g;\mathbb{Q})$.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

It is a well-known fact that there is in particular an equivalence of categories between the algebraic representations of the Lie group $\operatorname{Sp}(2g;\mathbb{C})$ and those of its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sp}(2g;\mathbb{C})$. I suspect that the same is true if we replace $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{Q}$. Where can I find a reference for this fact if it is indeed true?

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$ the equivalence is implemented by the exponential map. But there is no exponential map over $\mathbb{Q}$. So what is the functor you want to be an equivalence?

Comment: If you want to move to the rationals, then Lie groups is the wrong setting, and you need algebraic groups. In this case, for a semisimple and simply connected algebraic group $G$ over any field, there is an equivalence of categories between $G$-modules and locally finite modules for the algebra of distributions on $G$. In characteristic $0$, this algebra is the enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra for $G$, so this gives you the equivalence you want. This can be found in for example Jantzen's book.